# Low Price MP3 Player That can play music within folders

Tags: mp3-player

I am looking for a low cost Bluetooth MP3 Player.

I would like to drop my drop my music library into it like a flash drive without needing to install software on my computer, and for the player to loop through all of the uploaded music without having to manually switch folders.

Comment: @RohitGupta that is what he is asking, not what you should be asking him

Comment: What is the price range we talk about?

Answer (score 0):

Try the new Sony Walkman. It's cheap and has multiple settings for automatically navigating folders.